# Website doesn't show images stored in database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

Im making a website which is supposed to show records in a database including images. The texts show but the images won't. The problem lies within the  tag.

```php
    <?php
    while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <div class="col-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="card">
                  <img src="<?php echo $rows['Image'] ?>"/>
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2><?php echo $rows['PartijNaam'] ?></h2>
                        <p class="title"><?php echo $rows['Lijsttrekker'] ?></p>
                        <form action="information.php">
                            <p><input type="submit" class="button" href="information.php"></input></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: We need to know what `$rows` looks like. What does `$rows['Image']` contain?

Comment: try dumping the value of $rows['Image'] separately and see what that outputs

Comment: Are the images in a special sub-folder, such as uploads?

Comment: share a output of `$rows['Image']`

Comment: Aside: actually _storing_ images in your database is probably a bad decision. A more common pattern would be to store some kind of _pointer_ to an image, e.g. a local file path or a URL. It looks like you're trying to store a URL, but your title makes me wonder...

Comment: @Chris: Storing images in the database is a (good and easy) way to assert integrity of the data. So it's probably rather a good decision if you care about that.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton With that, you mean what it shows as on phpMyAdmin? Under 'Image' it says "[BLOB - 32.9 KiB]". I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton When I open the page, i see this: ��~f|O�����|��C�L�?�h�a�[�����>#�y�������8���